# Scraper downloading and saving just 20 images

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to download and save images using a scraper but it only downloads the first 20 images while I want it to download as many images as possible.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import os 

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=cats&sxsrf=ALeKk01diaA8AhwZsRpiMkZxaTUY6MuN4Q:1624119375856&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj62uGTjKTxAhWMIsAKHV12B74Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1848&bih=949"
folder = "images"

r = requests.get(url,stream=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")

images = soup.select("img")

try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder))
except:
    pass
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder))

i = 0 

for image in images:
    if i != 0:
        link = image["src"]

        with open(str(i) + ".jpg", "wb") as f:
            im = requests.get(link)
            f.write(im.content)
            print("Writing: ",i)
    
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code i get 109 jpeg

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import os 
my_UA="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.107"
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = my_UA
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=cats&sxsrf=ALeKk01diaA8AhwZsRpiMkZxaTUY6MuN4Q:1624119375856&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj62uGTjKTxAhWMIsAKHV12B74Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1848&bih=949"
folder = "images"

r = requests.get(url,stream=True,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
images = soup.select("img")
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder))
except:
    pass
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder))
i = 0 
print("total images found=",len(images))
for image in images:
    link=""
    if image.get("src"):
        link = image["src"]
    elif image.get("data-src"):
        link = image["data-src"]
    if link and not "image/gif;" in link:
        with open(str(i) + ".jpg", "wb") as f:
            im = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
            f.write(im.content)
            print("Writing: ",i)
        i += 1
```

-there are 2 properties "src" and "data-src"
-It skips gifs.
-For more files you can do it with selenium for example